# Unable to parse JSON data: JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX

Tags: php-7, cakephp-3.x

On a newly installed server running CakePHP 3.2.14, a call to `debug($myEntity)` displays the following error after displaying the entity without any visible problem:

```
An Internal Error Has Occurred

Error: Error executing command: Unable to parse JSON data: JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX - Syntax error, malformed JSON
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**  According to my tests, I get this error runing PHP7.0. I don't have this error running PHP5.6.

What does it mean?

Comment: Care to tell what `$myEntity` consists of?

Comment: @learner, you are right even if the name is quite self explainable, $myentity is an entity object. It's not the first `debug()` I call in my code but I don't understand why this one fails. I've added what it displays.

Comment: What happens if *you* `json_encode` `$myEntity` on PHP7 vs PHP5.x? This'll help work out whether the problem is with PHP7 or CakePHP.

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error message**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, after deeper searchs I found that te problem comes from a plugin.